Query with group show results inconsistent when I execute several times
Query with group show results inconsistent when I execute several times
I'm testing Druid version 25.0.0 with ingestion realtime from Kafka.
I have a table (my-tabla) with the following columns:
- __time: mapped from source data
- message: Format JSON
- path: String
- id

When I execute several time in Druid query frontend (admin panel) the following query
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Count", path
FROM "my-tabla"
GROUP BY (path)
ORDER by "Count" DESC

By count show for example the first time of execution:
11.256.000
Second time (increased as expected):
11.260.000
Third time: (unexpected because decrease)
10.300.000
I tried with different options from Frontend like:
- Use cache
- Use approximate TopN
- Use approximate Count(Distinct)

And other options of druid broker:
 druid.broker.cache.useCache=false
 druid.broker.cache.populateCache=false
 druid.broker.cache.useResultLevelCache=false
 druid.broker.cache.populateResultLevelCache=false

¿What configuration can produce this behavior?
I'm expecting that count by Path increase in new query executions

Please try and narrow down the issue by introducing the (recommended) __time-based filter or GROUP BY on it. (You should ALWAYS use __time in a Druid query). This will show if the issue is in the historical data (ie excluding real-time data), the real-time, or if this is something caused by the query execution pattern. You're right to disable approx COUNT as it's on by default - see the notebook in https://github.com/implydata/learn-druid

Also do take a look at later versions of Druid as these include the MSQ engine for async queries - might be a better API route for you if you need to scan more data.

I've seen similar things happen when a realtime ingestion task fails. This can, for instance, happen because of parse errors. Before the task fails, the query result would include the rows in the realtime segment being built. After the failure, the realtime segment is discarded and the result count goes down. If this is what happens, you would be able to see it in the task logs.
